# How can I dynamically set the tree views delete state?

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I've set my order_line to be editable and want to remove the delete button if it's not in draft mode. I attempted the following but the delete button remains:

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//tree" position="attributes">
  <attribute name="delete" domain="[(parent.state,'!=','draft')]"/>
</xpath>
```

Is it possible to dynamically set delete=false based on the draft state of the parent?

I tried this:

```
<record id="delete_drafts_only" model="ir.rule">
  <field name="name">You can only delete items with draft parents</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line"/>
  <field name="global" eval="True"/>
  <field name="domain_force">[('parent.state', '=', 'draft')]</field>
  <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

and

```
<record id="delete_drafts_only" model="ir.rule">
  <field name="name">You can only delete items with draft parents</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line"/>
  <field name="global" eval="True"/>
  <field name="domain_force">[('parent.state', '!=', 'draft')]</field>
  <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
  <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
  <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
  <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

But it doesn't seem to actually apply. The only thing that seem to be working is manipulating the `ir_model_access`, but that toggles it globally which isn't what I want.

[image]

Comment: why not make it readonly? do you need to edit it?

Comment: @StackUP I need to edit 1 field that I've added, yes.

Answer (score 2):

I have made [something similar](https://github.com/OCA/project-service/blob/8.0/project_baseuser/security/project_security.xml#L79) work, also using Record Rules.

The lines should have the delete access, so that the delete button can be available in the form, and the record Rule should deny delete access if certain conditions are met.

So your second Record Rule should work.
The catch is that the delete button will still be visible, but an Access error will be raised by the rule, effectively enforcing it.

You could try removing the `global` option and assigning the Rule to a group:

```
<record id="delete_drafts_only" model="ir.rule">
  <field name="name">You can only delete items with draft parents</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line"/>
  <field name="domain_force">[('parent.state', '!=', 'draft')]</field>
  <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
  <field name="perm_read" eval="True"/>
  <field name="perm_write" eval="True"/>
  <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
  <field name="perm_unlink" eval="False"/>
</record>
```

Comment: Right so I've spent a few hours trying to get this to work again. My `ir.rule` doesn't seem to take effect at all. Only toggling the group permission `ir.model.access` from sale seem to work. If you look at my screenshot I've disallowed any creation and deletion in any state across all the order line rules, but it doesn't stick. Does group permissions in `ir.model.access` always override `ir.rule`?

Comment: It's the other way around: `ir.rule` overrides (is checked _after_) `ir.model.access`, so `ir.model.access` should be more permissive, and then `ir.rule` add restrictions for certain conditions. This is working is the module I linked as an example.

Comment: Hmm, I think I tried both opt-in and opt-out but I will try again. I gave you the bounty in any case since it was about to time out.

Answer (score 1):

The "ir.rule" solution you wrote almost works: the delete button still stay visible, but when you try to save, it gives you an exception for invalid access.

Besides, the logic behind is different: In order to "disable" delete of a line you should use a negative logic. This worked for me:

```
<record id="delete_drafts_only" model="ir.rule">
  <field name="name">You can only delete items with draft parents</field>
  <field name="model_id" ref="sale.model_sale_order_line"/>
  <field name="domain_force">[('state', '=', 'draft')]</field>
  <field name="groups" eval="[(4,ref('base.group_user'))]"/>
  <field name="perm_read" eval="False"/>
  <field name="perm_write" eval="False"/>
  <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>
  <field name="perm_unlink" eval="True"/>
</record>
```

I suppose the semantic is:

- domain_force field point out which records of the model have to be considered
- perm_* fields indicate which operations cannot be executed (thus a "False" value means the operation can be executed and vice-versa)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting you can just make it invisible with given criteria

```
<xpath expr="//field[@name='order_line']//tree" position='attributes'>
<attribute name='invisible' attrs="{'invisible':[('parent.state','!=','draft')]}">1</attribute>
</xpath>
```

This is just a brief idea.. Just try it.

Comment: He doesn't want to hide the tree, but just the delete button.